# Error response from daemon: pull access denied for buildcontainer, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

**cloudbuild.yaml:**

```
steps:
- name: buildcontainer
args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/coffee2goserver:${SHORT_SHA}', '.']
- name: 'pushcontainer'
args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/coffee2goserver"]
```

**error:**

> Error response from daemon: pull access denied for buildcontainer,
>   repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Comment: I don't see any issue with the Dockerfile. Instead, try to add a step to ```docker login``` prior to calling the ```docker build```

Comment: You're building and pushing different names; the push command needs to include the `${SHORT_SHA}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Build doesn't provide any `buildcontainer` or `pushcontainer` images you can use in your builds (unless you have created them yourself).

You may use the official Docker image in your step like so:

```
steps:
- name: docker
args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/coffee2goserver:${SHORT_SHA}', '.']
- name: docker
args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/coffee2goserver:${SHORT_SHA}"]
```

The Docker build step is automatically set up with credentials for your [Cloud Build Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/permissions). These permissions are sufficient to interact directly with GCR.

Also, as David Maze@ mentioned in his comment, be careful to push your image with the same name it was build with, including the `${SHORT_SHA}` in this case.

Comment: I am doing `python manage.py migrate` and getting this error